# SQL query to find last chaining data from other column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need help to find last chaining data from other column and get the higher status

here is sample data:

[image]

`freed198` -> `anna1112` -> `jimmy908` -> `alison287` -> `summer7879`

because `summer7879` has higher status, so we choose `summer7879`

`gundre333` -> `joy657` -> `yero554` -> `susi889`

in the chaining `susi889` is not the higher status, we choose `yero554`

below expected result:

[image]

status:

- active = 2
- half active = 1
- inactive = 0

hopefully the query is optimized because the data is so big.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a [recursive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to populate the highest status, then in the CTE usage, use a [window function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-frames/) to take the maximum for each ColumnA. I'm unsure why your `freed198` example needed to go to `summer7879` as it already was active.

Comment: @danblack thanks for the info, because `freed198` has chaining to `anna1112`, `summer7879` doesn't have chaining (latest data)

Comment: your data has typos, jimmy1908 vs jimmy908, anna1112 vs anna112

Comment: please explain your expected results for ColumnA='yero554' and ='dondon986'?  since the status seems to belong to the ColumnB value, I don't see how or why ColumnA could be its own result.

Comment: and you have a half misspelled hafl

Comment: please don't say "the data is so big"; big to some people is thousands of rows, to others it's tens of billions of rows.  an actual row count would be good.

Comment: @ysth sorry my bad.. typos of data, already fixed.

Comment: yes you are correct the `Status` belong to `ColumnB`. about `yero554` and `dondon986` because in their groups chain, `yero554` and `dondon986` has highest `Status`. Ex: `yero554` has chain to `susi889` but `susi889` status is less than `yero554`, so the data will go up to find the highest status in their respective chain groups.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your data, and don't provide your table name or an indication of how you are ordering your results, and your expected results for ColumnA='yero554' and ColumnA='dondon986' don't make sense.  But this is the general approach I would take, using a recursive cte to walk each chain, keeping track of the best status found so far (and its ColumnB), then select the row with maximum depth:

```
with recursive foo_chain as (
    select
        id,
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        Status,
        1 depth,
        ColumnB last_chain,
        find_in_set(Status,'inactive,half active,active') best_status,
        ColumnB best_chain
    from foo

    union all

    select
        foo_chain.id,
        foo_chain.ColumnA,
        foo_chain.ColumnB,
        foo_chain.Status,
        depth+1,
        foo.ColumnB,
        # best status found so far
        greatest(foo_chain.best_status, find_in_set(foo.Status,'inactive,half active,active')),
        # save this foo as best if status at least as good as we've found so far
        case when find_in_set(foo.Status,'inactive,half active,active') >= foo_chain.best_status
            then foo.ColumnB
            else foo_chain.best_chain
        end
    from foo_chain join foo on foo.ColumnA=foo_chain.last_chain
)
select ColumnA, ColumnB, Status, best_chain Result
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ColumnA, ColumnB, Status order by depth desc) preference
    from foo_chain
) f
where preference=1
order by id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9eqJGxQr)

Comment: Thank you for your help, `Status` is belong to `ColumnB`, `yero554` and `dondon986` has highest in their groups chain. Ex: `yero554` has chain to `susi889` but `susi889` status is less than `yero554`, so the data will go up to find the highest status in their respective chain groups.

Comment: ah, I was assuming Status was about the relationship of ColumnA to ColumnB, not just about column B.  then the initial unioned query just needs to also check for ColumnA's status (from a row where it is ColumnB).  but what should happen if a ColumnA value appears multiple times in ColumnB with different Statuses?

Comment: just get the highest `Status`

Comment: when the last chain data don't have status `Active` go up to find highest status.. while go up and early found status `Active` just stop and get the data from `ColumnB` else keep go up to find the highest status.. if no highest status found just get last chaining which is from `ColumnB`